# How to make a container lay on another container flutter

Tags: flutter

What would be the best approach to create this kind of UI:

[image]

Both containers are stretched to device width. Container 1 has a solid background and Container 2 has rounded corners on top and touches the safe area at the bottom. Both containers have fixed height.

Is the best method to use a Stack widget and position both containers? Or is there any another way to achieve it without stack?

Comment: Can you post some code that you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use bottomCenter alignment in the parent container like this:

```
Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.blue,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //<--- Like this
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
          ),
        ),
```

but i think the best approach would be the stack approach if you want to add content to the blue part and is more flexible

```
 Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: in the second example if there's requirement to adding child widgets developer will have the headache of widget going behind the white container as the blue container has the size of full screen.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, if you want to add a widget on top the white Container you have to make it a child of that container and a Stack works based on hierarchy the first widget in the stack becomes the bottom widget and so on

Comment: No, you didn't understood my concern, i mean what if we need to add the widgets in the child of the blue container! Then as the Blue container has the size of the full screen some widget may go behind the white container as in stack white colored container is on top of the blue container

Answer (score 0):

This code would be helpful for following design:

```
 Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    body: Column(
      children: [
        const Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
        Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(40)),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ))
      ],
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two containers, making use of the margin property:

```
    Container(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.40),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Also, don't be afraid of using the Stack widget, I know positioning is a headache, but it's a very useful solution and sometimes it's the only one.